# Regression with categorical IVs (non-binary) and DVs (binary)

Tags: regression, categorical-data, many-categories

I'd like to run a regression so that I can determine the standardized Beta-weights of five categorical IVs (some with more than 2 levels) on a categorical DV (binary). I've ruled out the following techniques for various reasons:

- no to standard linear regression (non-continuous variables)
- no to loglinear regression (study design was repeated measures)
- no to multinomial regression (only one outcome variable with two categories)

Is there a way to get around these analysis confounds that are resulting from my study design? Any help at all would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want a nonlinear multilevel model with a binomial link.

These are a generalization of logistic regression to allow for repeated measures.